# How to keep mail messages on servers for Apple mail?

Tags: mail.app, google, yahoo

My "late 2013" Mac Pro has a small internal SSD. Since Yahoo Mail and Google Mail have large storage on their servers, I don't see reasons for me to store mail messages on my local SSD. Can Apple Mail client be configured in a way that it only stores, say, 1 month of mail messages locally? Then it can fetch older mail messages on demand. Can I configure Apple Mail to do that?

Comment: Gmail has a 15GB storage limit on free accounts and Yahoo has a 1TB storage limit on free accounts, so not unlimited.

Comment: If you are a Google Suite for Education customer, there is no storage limit unless there are 4 or fewer users, in which case the cap is 1 TB per user.

Comment: If you specify the default option (I think...) which is IMAP then messages are kept on the server and only headers are downloaded. Is that not working for you?

Comment: @SteveChambers I can not find that Option in my Google IMAP settings.

Comment: GMail > Settings (Gear Icon) > Forwarding and POP/IMAP > IMAP Access > Enable IMAP access

Comment: @SteveChambers I would like the Apple Mail client behave like the mail client on the iPhone. The iPhone mail client downloads and keeps a few weeks' messages on the local storage. The mail messages are still stored in the mail servers and one can always go back there to retrieve them. Can the Mac Mail do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can begin with Setting the Download Attachments to None in you Mac Mail.

That is the biggest part of mails anyway, the rest is just text.

If you are up to the task you can then export all attachments out of your Local storage.

They are located in `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data/Library/Mail Downloads/`

You can also **Export** all of the mail box, to for example iCloud.
It just makes a copy of it, so you can now delete mails on your Mac, and get them again later.

To do so right click on the mailbox and use Export.

Did you know that for $1/Month you can upgrade your iCloud to 50GB.

[image]

Now if you want to automate that, like keep emails for a month then Export, you will need a Automator process for that.